# PHP: date() returns a zero date

Tags: php, date

Hey guys i'm trying to use the date() function for my website but when I do it returns 0000-00-00. I am using this code:

```
$date = date();
```

Using that it will return "0000-00-00".

What could be causing this? Sorry I can't provide much more information as that is the only thing I can think to give you.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can't call date without at least 1 param

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: If you want to get the format from your example, you should put in 'date("Y-m-d")' - see the manual of date for the exact format: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.date.php

Comment: @Lars thanks alot, I think I was using an Invalid date format so it was returning null.

Comment: The code you posted in your question does not return `"0000-00-00"`.

Answer (score 5):

As yes123 says, [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) requires a parameter that defines what format you want to get the results in. If you want yyyy-mm-dd, use `date( 'Y-m-d' )`. If you just want the timestamp use [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Docs for the DateTime functions [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

Comment: This answer would have made a great comment.  :)

Comment: Need 50 reputation to comment on anything :( Almost there though :)